# For-loop/ simple data extraction and comparison in R

Tags: for-loop, conditional-statements

In this example dataset i have created a column called 'Var'.  This is the result i would like from a the code.  The pseudo-code to give Var is like this : For each ID_Survey, compare the Distance in sequence, if the difference between sequential Distances is 10, then Var=1, otherwise Var=0.  Var should be 1 for both elements of the sequence where the difference is 10.

```
#Generate data
ID_Survey=rep(seq(1,3,1),each=4)
Distance=       c(0,25,30,40,50,160,170,190,200,210,1000,1010)
Var=            c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,   1,   1);
TestData=data.frame(cbind(ID_Survey,Distance,Var))
TestData
```

I can use a simple for-loop like this, which nearly works, but it trips-up when moving between ID_Survey.

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(TestData)-1)){
TestData$Var2[i]=(TestData$Distance[i+1]==TestData$Distance[i]+10)}
```

I need to incorporate the above into a function which splits the data.frame into groups based on ID_Survey.  I'm trying to build something like the following...

```
New6=do.call(rbind, by(TestData,list(TestData$ID_Survey), 
FUN=function(x) 
for (i in nrow(x)){ #loop must build an argument then return it.  
#conditional statements in here.  
return(x[i,])})); #loop appears to return 1st argument only.
```

... but i can't get the for-loop to operate inside the by-statement.

Any guidance much appreciated.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data.table function (.SD) manages separating and collating chunks of the data.frame (as defined by ID_Survey) after it has been sent to a function.  No doubt someone else will have a more elegant solution, but this seems to do the job:

```
library(data.table)
ComPair=function(a,b){V=ifelse(a==b-10,TRUE,FALSE);return(V)}
TestFunction=function(FData){
  if(nrow(FData)>1){
  for(i in 1:(nrow(FData)-1)){
    V=ComPair(FData$Distance[i],FData$Distance[i+1])
    if(V==1){ FData$Var2[i]=V;FData$Var2[i+1]=V}
  }
  };return(FData)}

TestData_dt=data.table(TestData)
TestData2=TestData_dt[,TestFunction(.SD),ID_Survey]
TestData2
```